# Derivative of a function in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be a differential function. Let $Df(x)$ be the derivative of f at $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Which of the following is/are correct?

1. $Df(0)(u)=0 \forall u\in\mathbb{R}^m$
2. $Df(x)(u)=0 \forall u\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and some $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ only if $f$ is a constant.
3. $Df(x)(u)=0 \forall u\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and all $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ only if $f$ is a constant.
4. If $f$ is not a constant function, then $Df(x)$ is a one to one function for some $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$

This is where I am stuck:

1. What is the meaning of $Df(x)(u)$?
2. "Ignoring" (u), I intuitively feel 1 is wrong, 3 is correct, (and hence 2 is wrong), and I have no clue about 4. But intuition cannot be trusted always.

Any hints towards the answer are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to understand what a derivative at x is in this context.

$Df(x)$ is the linear function such that

$$
\begin{array} 
    .Df(x) : & \mathbb{R}^m & \to    & \mathbb{R}^m \\ 
            & u            & \mapsto & Df(x)(u)
\end{array}
$$

Personnally, I find it more clear to write it as $Df_x$, to show that $x$ is a parameter.

And it verify

$$f(x+h) = f(x) + Df(x)(u) + \|u\|\epsilon(u)$$

where $$\lim_{u\to 0 \in \mathbb{R}^m} \epsilon(u) = 0$$

For functions $f : \mathbb{R}^m  \to \mathbb{R}^m$, you can see $Df(x)$ as a $m\times m$ matrix $M$ and $Df(x)(u) = Mu$

And for the question 4, what can you say about $Df(x,y)$ of the function $f(x,y) = (x,0)$? Is it a constant function? Is the matrix $Df(x,y)$ inversible for some $(x,y)$?

Comment: Looks like the question deals with one of my blind spots, I need to dig into the basics a bit first. Anyway, thank you. The way you have explained it, I'm sure I will understand it once I get my basics set! (marking the answer right)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:

$Df(x)$ is a linear map. So you can think of $Df(x)$ as a matrix and $u$ the vector it's acting on. Ie, just matrix multiplication. Perhaps more formally:

\begin{align*}
DF:\mathbb{R}^m&\rightarrow \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n)\\
x&\mapsto DF(x)
\end{align*}
where $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the set of linear maps on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The associated matrix of the linear map $DF(x)$ is simply the Jacobian matrix of $F$ evaluated at the point $x$.

To answer your second question:

Let's think about statement 4)

$f$ not constant $\Rightarrow$ There exists $x\in \mathbb{R}^M$ such that $\det(Df(x))\neq 0$.

By contraposition this is equivalent to:

For all $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$, $\det(Df(x))=0\Rightarrow f$ is a constant function.

Does this help? Perhaps try to prove this statement? Or maybe find a counter example? Can you find a non-constant function $F:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $DF(x)=0$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that since $f$ is from    $\mathit{R^m}$  to $   \mathit{R^m}  $ i.e. $f(x_1,...,x_m)=(f_1(x),..., f_m(x))$, then its Frechet Derivative $Df$ is : $Df:    \mathit{R^m}\mapsto \mathrm{L}(\mathit{R^m},\mathit{R^m})   $, where $\mathrm{L}(\mathit{R^m},\mathit{R^m})   $ is the vecotr space of all linear maps from   $\mathit{R^m}$  to $   \mathit{R^m}  $.
Thus, for any $x \in  \mathit{R^m}  $, $Df(x) \in \mathrm{L}(\mathit{R^m},\mathit{R^m}) $. Note also that the space $\mathrm{L}(\mathit{R^m},\mathit{R^m})$ is isomorphic to the space $M_{m \times m}$ the space of all $m \times m $ matrices. So $Df(x) $ can be simply regarded as an $m \times m $ matrix where each component is a partial defivative : $\frac{\partial f_i }{\partial x_j}$ . Hence, For any $u \in \mathit{R^m}$, $Df(x)(u)$ is well defined, and you can see it as a matrix-vector multiplication: $Df(x)$ is $m \times m $ matrix, and $u$ is a $m \times 1$ vector, so the over all result implies $Df(x)(u)$ is a $m \times 1$ vector.

Now, agian to your statements,

1. is clearly false.
2. It is also false because simply even if $f$ is non constant with $Df(x) \neq 0_{m \times m}$, you would find some $u \in  \mathit{R^m} $ with $Df(x)(u) \neq 0$. Counter Example: $f(x_1,x_2)=(2x_1-2x_2, -4x_1+4x_2)$  non constant and   $Df(x)=  \begin{pmatrix} 2 &-2 \\ -4  & 4   \end{pmatrix}$, and  $Df(x) \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1   \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0  \end{pmatrix}$ $.
3. I think it is True, simply try it for dimesion two and same result holds for any dimension as: $Df(x) =  \begin{pmatrix} a &b \\ c  & d  \end{pmatrix}$ and $Df(x)(u)=0 $ for every $u$ .  So for $u= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0   \end{pmatrix}$ implies $a, c =0$, and for $u= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}$ implies $b,d=0$. Which implies that $\frac{\partial f_i }{\partial x_j}= 0$ for all $i, j$. Hence $f$ is constant .
4. If $f$ not constant, this does not implies that $Df(x)$  is an invertible matrix i.e. $f$ is not bijective. Here you have a square matrix so  injective(one to one), surjective and bijective are equivalent.  Simply take counter example the same as part 2.